# Kotlin - can't acces elements [Ljava.lang.Object

Tags: java, kotlin

i'm having some issues with a java library in Kotlin.

I can't find a way to access the elements of a [Ljava.lang.Object
I'm trying to cast it in array or list; cant find any documentation about this.

If anyone can give me a head up.
thanks in advance

EDIT:
Some code. This is the java class i'm implementig in kotlin, is an api to connect to Odoo, so there ir other libraries includes, xmlrpc and other api classes. I'll try to keep it simple

```
public class Response {

private final boolean isSuccessful;
private final Exception errorCause;
private final Object responseObject;
private final Object[] responseObjectAsArray;

public Response(final Exception errorCause) {
    this.isSuccessful = false;
    this.errorCause = errorCause;
    this.responseObject = null;
    this.responseObjectAsArray = new Object[0];
}

public Response(final Object responseObject) {
    this.isSuccessful = true;
    this.errorCause = null;
    this.responseObject = responseObject;
    if (responseObject instanceof Object[]) {
        this.responseObjectAsArray = (Object[]) responseObject;
    } else {
        this.responseObjectAsArray = new Object[]{responseObject};
    }
}

public boolean isSuccessful() {
    return isSuccessful;
}

public Throwable getErrorCause() {
    return errorCause;
}

public Object getResponseObject() {
    return responseObject;
}

public Object[] getResponseObjectAsArray() {
    return responseObjectAsArray;
}
}
```

here is the function from the lib

```
 public RowCollection searchAndReadObject(final FilterCollection filter, final String[] fields, int offset, int limit, String order) throws XmlRpcException, OdooApiException {

   String[] fieldArray = fields == null ? new String[]{} : fields;
   Object[] preparedFilters = validateFilters(filter);

   Response response = command.searchAndReadObject(modelName, preparedFilters,fieldArray,offset,limit,order);

   FieldCollection fieldCol = new FieldCollection();
   for (String fieldName : fieldArray) {
       for (Field fld : allFields) {
           if (fld.getName().equals(fieldName)) {
               fieldCol.add(fld);
           }
       }
   }

   return new RowCollection(response.getResponseObjectAsArray(), fieldCol);

   }

public RowCollection(Object [] openERPResultSet, FieldCollection fields) throws OdooApiException{
    for (int i = 0; i < openERPResultSet.length; i++){
        //aca tengo que chequear el objecto
        Row row = new Row((HashMap<String, Object>) openERPResultSet[i], fields);
        this.add(row);
    }
}
```

and the row from rowcollection

```
public Row (HashMap<String, Object> openERPResult, FieldCollection fields) throws OdooApiException{
    this.openERPResult = openERPResult;
    this.fields = fields;
    // This is a new row, add entries for every field
    if (openERPResult.isEmpty()){
        this.put("id", 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++)
            this.put(fields.get(i).getName(),null);
    }

}
```

From Command the searchAndReadObject

```
public Response searchAndReadObject(String objectName, Object[] filter, String[] fields, int offset, int limit, String order) throws XmlRpcException {
    Response readResult;
    Object offsetParam = offset < 0 ? false : offset;
    Object limitParam = limit < 0 ? false : limit;
    Object orderParam = order == null || order.length() == 0 ? false : order;
    if (this.session.getServerVersion().getMajor() >= 8) {
        readResult = new Response(session.executeCommandWithContext(objectName, "search_read", new Object[]{filter, fields,offsetParam,limitParam,orderParam}));
    } else {
        //TODO: Have to be rewritten/deleted considering the previous call
        readResult = new Response(session.executeCommand(objectName, "search_read", new Object[]{filter, fields, session.getContext(),offsetParam,limitParam,orderParam}));
    }

    return readResult;
}
```

And this is the code in Kotlin, is a simple access to a record:

```
object Constant{
 const val URL :String= "localhost" //where im running Odoo 8
 const val PORT: Int=8069
 const val DB = "DataBase"


 }
 val sesion=Session(Constant.URL,Constant.PORT,Constant.DB,"admin","admin")
 sesion.startSession()
 val filter= FilterCollection()
 filter.add("user_id","=",sesion!!.userID)
 val clientAd=sesion!!.getObjectAdapter("res.partner")

 val clients=clientAd.searchAndReadObject(filter, arrayOf("name", "city_id", "internal_code", "phone"),1,1,"id ASC")
```

the problem is when i try to access the city_id column

```
[
{
    "internal_code": "1234",
    "city_id": [ 21, "city name" ],
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Agrolait"
}]
```

clients[0]["city_id"] is a object[]. i need to access the elements

```
clients[0]["city_id"]
res14: kotlin.Any! = [Ljava.lang.Object;@38f1f6c9
```

i hope this can clearify my question

Comment: please share some code, where you have the issue. That makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Please show us the lines of code that fail along with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Well...
I modified the java library casting the Object[] to a List inside the library.
Then in Kotlin i can cast the java.util.ArrayList into an ArrayList from kotlin.
I thought the casting would be automatic, but i have to do it implicit.

This is a workarround to get it working, but still cant cast the object[] to an array.
Hope this can be usefull to someone

Comment: You can't cast an array to a list (`myArray as List<something>` in Kotlin or `(List<something>) myArray` in Java); they're unrelated types, so that would give a ClassCastException.  However, you could _convert_ an array to a list (`myArray.toList()`).  Remember: a cast doesn't convert a value to a new type; a cast promises the compiler that it's _already_ the new type.

Comment: Is there a way to cast object[] to anything in kotlin ( list, array or something I can iterate thru)?

Comment: You can iterate through an array already: Kotlin provides a host of extension methods on arrays, letting you call `.forEach()` or `.iterator()` (which in turn lets you `for (item in myArray)…`), as well as `.toList()`, `.toSet()`, `.map()`, and loads more.

Comment: its not working for me
`usuario[0]["partner_id"]
res12: kotlin.Any! = [Ljava.lang.Object;@c1d9c40`

`usuario[0]["partner_id"].forEach()
error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<???>.forEach(action: (???) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out ???, ???>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<???, ???>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
usuario[0]["partner_id"].forEach()
                         ^`

Comment: What type is `usario`?  If the compiler can't tell that one of its elements is itself an array, or doesn't know what the element type of _that_ array is, then of course it won't know how to iterate through it.  (In that case, you'd have to cast it first — or, better still, use the right types originally.)  But all this would be easier if you posted [a _short_ example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we could look at and run.

Comment: The type of usuario is a array of custom class, the "partner_id" is an array with not type (object []). the elements od "partner_id" are ID and Name (Integer and String respectvly).
That's why i've modified the java library, then the types are right to cast in kotlin. I thought kotlin automatically convert the types of the array, so i read the documentation and i find out i was wrong.